# Careers 2.0 invitation profile creation fails

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, error-message, invitation

Today, I got a mail with an invite to create an account on Stack Overflow Careers 2.0. But when I try to login using the Google OpenId, after the "Confirm OpenId" page, it always give me an error when I hit the "Log In" button. And when I try to login directly from the frontpage, it give me a "cookies" error with every browser I'll tried.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try to a/ log in when in incognito / private browsing mode and b/ if that doesn't work try to log in from a different location / network?

Comment: Actually it looks like this is a temporary issue with our authentication system. Please hold off for a few minutes, we'll provide an update as soon as this is fixed.

Comment: Thank both for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try again.

This was a technical problem with our authentication system and should be fixed by now.